A question about how substitution methods work in integration
In trigonometric substitution, it's common to say $t=\tan(x/2)$ for integrals involving $R(\sin x,\cos x)$. However, this is also done when $\tan(x/2)$ can be undefined for values where the integrand is continuous. I have seen that $t$ is defined in a way that excludes such values, but if the integral still exists there, wouldn't that mean that the function we find in such indefinite integrals is just an approximation? This question also applies to $t=1/x$. I also include my question about how we can use Pythagoras' theorem for real $t$ values (which may not even fit in a triangle?) when converting $t$ to $x$ after a trigonometric substitution, since they seem to be related.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is crystal clear ! This robot has to be re-programmed !

I wonder if the bot takes into account grammar and MathJax -- because it is awful on those fronts.

I don't see an issue here : for a definite integral with bounds $a<b$, there is no problem : $t \in (2\arctan(a),2\arctan(b)) \subset (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Welcome to MSE! <> To clarify: (i) Do you know the "stereographic" picture of the unit circle motivating the $t = \tan(x/2)$ substitution? It's continuous (in a suitable sense) even where $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, which perhaps explains your first question. (ii) Whether or no, it might help to include a specific example of a definite integral that looks questionable.

I don't know of that picture and I couldn't find it. I've noticed the integrand is continous, but for values where cos(x/2)=0 this substitution doesn't seem to hold (t is even defined that way). For the second part it's about any integral where pythagoras theorem is used to compute stuff, integral of 1/(sqrt(x^2-a^2)) is an example.

I'll try learning how to format MathJax next time I ask a question. I don't see how my grammar is awful though, feel free to point out my mistakes. Also is there a way to reply to people in comments?

Please edit your question to show a particular example of what you're talking about. Remember - substitutions only work when the domains make sense in both the new and old variable.

To reply to people in comments, precede their user name with the @ symbol. When you start typing their user name, typically you'll see their full user name appear and you can simply select it.
